# How to replace column values based on previous value by condition and select rows from dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have dataframe with two columns X1 and X2

**first thing:**
In X2 i have value 0 and 1 , if in X2 value is 1 when this change from 1 to zero then in next 20 rows should be 1 not zero.

for example :

```
X2=(0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

desired X2=(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

**Second thing:** if `X1=0` and `X2=1` then select rows from dataframe until `X2` value remains 1
I tried this piece of code but it selects only one row.

```
df1=df[(df['X1'] == 0) & (df['X2'] ==1)]
```

Comment: Please provide a sample Daytaframe in order to understand your question better.

Comment: These are two different questions and should probably be asked separately. Also please provide the code you have tried so far.

Comment: @ecortazar  for first problem X2  is column of dataframe

Comment: @john sloper the code that i tried for second problem

Comment: @Nickel The code for the Second thing is correct. Are you sure there are multiple rows that fulfill this in the dataframe?

Comment: @John Sloper, this code is selecting one row because the first codition changed after one row , even X1 value change from to 2 or 3 but if X2 still is 1 then should select the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited to include both parts:

```
# First Thing:
df['X2'] = df['X2'].replace({0: np.nan}).ffill(limit=20).fillna(0)

# Second Thing:
df.loc[(df['X1'] == 0) & (df['X2'] == 1), 'new X2'] = 1
df.loc[(df['X2'] == 0), 'new X2'] = 0
df['new X2'] = df['new X2'].ffill()
df.loc[df['new X2'] == 1] # Selected Rows
```

Comment: That is very neat. It does change the dtype to float though. May or may not be a problem.

Comment: an astype(int) at the end couldn't hurt. It would just make the solution a bit uglier.

Comment: @ ecortazar first problem is solved , but second problem code is not working, its give the whole dataframe rows not only selected rows

Comment: @Nickel Sorry,. though it was clear you needed to do df[df['new X2']] to see only the selected. I've amended the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your dataframe is not big so you could use easily loop to resolve your problem:

```
#first prog
index = 0
while index < df.shape[0]:
    if index + 1 < df.shape[0] and df['X2'][index] == 1 and df['X2'][index + 1] == 0:
        df.loc[index +1: index + 20,'X2'] = 1            #set 1 to next 20 rows
        break;
    index = index + 1 

print(df)
```

---

```
#second prog assuming you have a column X1/X2
df['select'] = False
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index > 0 and df['select'][index - 1] == True and row.X2 == 1:
        df.loc[index, 'select'] = True
    if row.X1 == 0 and row.X2 == 1:
        df.loc[index, 'select'] = True

df = df[df['select'] == True].drop('select', axis=1) 

print(df)
```

Comment: if dataframe is not big your code is working well , but i think if my dataframe size will increase it will take long time to finish this loops

Comment: @ Frenchy Sorry i forget to mention data size , i have data more than 10000 rows

Comment: you have right, loop is not good when you begins to have more than 5000 rows in this case you have lot of others solutions but as you havent indicate the number of rows of your dataframe, i have choosen a soluton easy to understant.. for the first prog loop or not loop is not the question, because only the first test is trapped. and you dont win lot of time, its just for the second prog the problem could exist

Comment: for the second things you have just one step, followings your explanation there is only one step, you dont precise if the process goes on when the first is done (first next 20 rows = 1).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to the "First thing" using numpy.

```
import numpy as np

locs =np.where(df['X2'].diff() == -1)[0]
for loc in locs:
    df.loc[slice(loc, loc+20), 'X2'] = 1
```